# How to change the look of an template instantiation like in std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

a `std::function` object is created like this:

```
std::function<int(int)> f = ...
```

since `<int(int)>` is not what i usually know from a template i would like to know how to do soemthing like this in my own class?
Like could we us for example in map templates like `map<std::string -> int>` ?

Comment: `int(int)` is your usual type parameter (it's a type of a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`), it's not a magical syntax thingy, so `std::string -> int` is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template parameter is a type parameter. Like every type template parameter. So you wont be able to create new syntax like the map example you stated.

`std::function` is specialized to extract parameters from the signature you send as a type.

Take this code for example:

```
template<typename>
struct MyFunction;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct MyFunction<R(Args...)> {
    // do whatever you want
};
```

A type like this can be aliased too:

```
using myFunctionType = int(double);

void doThings(myFunctionType* f) {
    // the type of f is int(*)(double), a function pointer.
}
```

Or you can extract this type with [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```
// the following line is equivalent to using myFunctionType = int(double);
using myFunctionType = std::remove_pointer<int(*)(double)>::type;
```

So basically, the type `int(double)` is a function type, usually it's used with pointers. In out case, our type is a function type that returns a `int` and take a `double` as parameter. There is no magic syntax here.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the syntax you are looking for is possible.

`std::function` works something like so:

```
template < typename Sig > struct function;

template < typename R, typename ... Params >
struct function<R(Params...)>
{
    // stuff and more stuff
};
```

Signatures are types.  You then partially specialize, as above, to get the underlying types...like the return type and the parameter types.

But you can't just throw in arbitrary syntax to a template and expect it to work.  The language has to support it, is it does in the case of signatures.